# Transit time: Lima to Ft. Lauderdale, then on to New York

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit

Is a 2 hour layover enough time to check through customs from Lima, Peru and then take the local flight from Fort Lauderdale to New York?

Comment: Are both the flights together on one PNR (Passenger Name Record), or are the flights separate and you have two PNRs ?

Answer (score 3):

If this is single ticket on Jet Blue, the answer is yes.

You have a very good chance of making the connection as is and even if there is a major delay and/or you get snagged in immigration, baggage, customs and/or security, Jet Blue will simply put you on the next flight. You are arriving at 6:50am, and there plenty of non-stop JetBlue flights from FLL to JFK on the same day.

If this NOT a single ticket, then the answer is a big fat NO.